# Get list of fields for index in kibana plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana, kibana-5

I am developing a kibana drop down filter plugin and I want to get the list of all fields in particular index in client side to list them in drop down menu.
How to get them?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:  you need to send the next query to elasticsearch:

```
GET /.kibana/index-pattern/_search
```

There you will find the definition of all index pattern

Option 2: you need to send the next query to elasticsearch:

```
GET /myIndex/_mapping
```

Comment: Thanks lax, I got this. I am developping a plugin with angularjs and in my controller, I want to know how to get the lists of fields. Thanks

Comment: Did you create the plugin with yoeman generator kibana plugin?

Comment: Yes I do. I finally find a solution. Thanks you. I have one more question please. I'm trying now to develop some kibana plugins based on d3js but i don't know how to integrate d3js and kibana. And how to get data from elasticsearch

Comment: To get data from elasticsearch, please look at https://github.com/Webiks/kibana-API/blob/master/server/routes.js, use the variable callWithRequest